# Backup failed message "error processing remote manifest"

Tags: backup, gnupg, duplicity

I tried to back up and got this error message:

```
Backup Failed

Error processing remote manifest (duplicity-inc.20180809T151337Z.to.20180816T192555Z.manifest.gpg): GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: WARNING: "--no-use-agent" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: Bad session key
===== End GnuPG log =====
```

How should I fix this error?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on Fujitsu AH557 and I experience [this erorr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jK2M.png) also.